# Oracle - Split a record into multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a schedule table for each month schedule. And this table also has days off within that month. I need a result set that will tell working days and off days for that month.
Eg.

```
    CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE(sch_yyyymm varchar2(6), sch varchar2(20), sch_start_date date, sch_end_date date);

INSERT INTO SCHEDULE VALUES('201703','Working Days', to_date('03/01/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('03/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'));

INSERT INTO SCHEDULE VALUES('201703','Off Day', to_date('03/05/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('03/07/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'));

INSERT INTO SCHEDULE VALUES('201703','off Days', to_date('03/08/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('03/10/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'));

INSERT INTO SCHEDULE VALUES('201703','off Days', to_date('03/15/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('03/15/2017','mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

Using SQL or PL/SQL I need to split the record with Working Days and Off Days. 
From above records I need result set as:

```
201703  Working Days 03/01/2017 - 03/04/2017
201703  Off Days     03/05/2017 - 03/10/2017
201703  Working Days 03/11/2017 - 03/14/2017
201703  Off Days     03/15/2017 - 03/15/2017
201703  Working Days 03/16/2017 - 03/31/2017
```

Thank You for your help.

Comment: So you want to select the entire table?  Just have a dash in between the two columns? As one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: I've had a bit more of a think, and this approach works fine for your insert records above - however, it misses records where there are not continuous "off day" periods.  I need to have a bit more of a think and will then make some changes**

I've put together a test using the `lead` and `lag` functions and a self join.

The upshot is you self-join the "Off Days" onto the existing tables to find the overlaps.  Then calculate the start/end dates on either side of each record.  A bit of logic then lets us work out which date to use as the final start/end dates.

SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ac4e/28) - I used Postgres as the Oracle function wasn't working but it should translate ok.

```
select  sch,
        /* Work out which date to use as this record's Start date */
        case when prev_end_date is null then sch_start_date
             else off_end_date + 1
        end as final_start_date,
        /* Work out which date to use as this record's end date */
        case when next_start_date is null then sch_end_date
             when next_start_date is not null and prev_end_date is not null then next_start_date - 1
             else off_start_date - 1
        end as final_end_date
from (
select  a.*,
        b.*,
        /* Get the start/end dates for the records on either side of each working day record */
        lead( b.off_start_date ) over( partition by a.sch_start_date order by b.off_start_date ) as next_start_date,
        lag( b.off_end_date ) over( partition by a.sch_start_date order by b.off_start_date ) as prev_end_date
from    (
          /* Get all schedule records */
          select sch,
                 sch_start_date,
                 sch_end_date
          from   schedule
        ) as a
        left join
        (
          /* Get all non-working day schedule records */
          select sch as off_sch,
                 sch_start_date as off_start_date,
                 sch_end_date as off_end_date
          from   schedule
          where  sch <> 'Working Days'
        ) as b
        /* Join on "Off Days" that overlap "Working Days" */
        on a.sch_start_date <= b.off_end_date
        and a.sch_end_date >= b.off_start_date
        and a.sch <> b.off_sch
 ) as c
 order by final_start_date
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can take it from here and make it works. Marking the response as right. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help!  I'm still keen to get it working out of interest, so I'll keep tinkering.  The problem I encountered was that the self-join needs to generate n+1 records per working day period, where n is the number of overlapping off day periods.  The code above doesn't reliably do that at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you had a dates table this would have been easier.

You can construct a dates table using a recursive cte and `join` on to it. Then use the difference of row number approach to classify rows with same schedules on consecutive dates into one group and then get the `min` and `max` of each group which would be the start and end dates for a given sch. *I assume there are only 2 sch values `Working Days` and `Off Day`.*

```
with dates(dt) as (select date '2017-03-01' from dual
                   union all
                   select dt+1 from dates where dt < date '2017-03-31')
,groups as (select sch_yyyymm,dt,sch,
            row_number() over(partition by sch_yyyymm order by dt) 
            - row_number() over(partition by sch_yyyymm,sch order by dt) as grp       
            from (select s.sch_yyyymm,d.dt,
                  /*This condition is to avoid a given date with 2 sch values, as 03-01-2017 - 03-31-2017 are working days 
                    on one row and there is an Off Day status for some of these days. 
                    In such cases Off Day would be picked up as sch*/
                  case when count(*) over(partition by d.dt) > 1 then min(s.sch) over(partition by d.dt) else s.sch end as sch
                  from dates d
                  join schedule s on d.dt >= s.sch_start_date and d.dt <= s.sch_end_date 
                 ) t
            )    
select sch_yyyymm,sch,min(dt) as start_date,max(dt) as end_date
from groups 
group by sch_yyyymm,sch,grp
```

I couldn't get the recursive cte running in Oracle. Here is a demo using SQL Server.

[`Sample Demo in SQL Server`](http://rextester.com/XUECB3629)